# How we can merge multidimensional array with JavaScript or underscore or lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How we can merge and join key value this code(javascript or undescore or lodash).

**Array Data:**

```
[[
    {
      "Product": "Men's Cut and Sewn",
      "Monday": 13,
      "Tuesday": 1.29,
      "Thursday": 10,
      "Friday": 2,
      "Saturday": 2.1,
      "Sunday": 12
    },
    {
      "Product": "Men's Inner",
      "Monday": 10,
      "Tuesday": 1.29,
      "Wednesday ": 2.6,
      "Thursday": 4.9,
      "Friday": 2,
      "Saturday": 20,
      "Sunday": 12
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Product": "Men's Cut and Sewn",
      "Monday": 10,
      "Tuesday": 45,
      "Wednesday": 45,
      "Thursday": 23,
      "Friday": 2,
      "Saturday": 3,
      "Sunday": 2
    },
    {
      "Product": "Men's Inner",
      "Monday": 1,
      "Tuesday": 1,
      "Thursday": 34,
      "Friday": 5,
      "Saturday": 34,
      "Sunday": 34
    }
  ]]
```

**Expectation Data:**

```
[{
 {
      "Product": "Men's Cut and Sewn",
      "Monday": 23,
      "Tuesday": 2.58,
      "Wednesday": 45,
      "Thursday": 33,
      "Friday": 4,
      "Saturday": 5.1,
      "Sunday": 14
    },
    {
      "Product": "Men's Inner",
      "Monday": 11,
      "Tuesday": 2.29,
      "Wednesday ": 2.6,
      "Thursday": 38.9,
      "Friday": 7,
      "Saturday": 54,
      "Sunday": 46
    }
}]
```

I tried with this javaScript code

```
var finalArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

  if (i < arr.length - 1 && finalArr.length > 0) {
    var arr1 = finalArr;
    var arr2 = arr[i]
  } else {
    var arr1 = arr[i];
    var arr2 = arr[i + 1];
  }

  for (let obj1 of arr1) {
    var sampleObj = {};

    for (let obj2 of arr2) {
      if (obj1.Product === obj2.Product) {
        sampleObj.Product = obj1.Product;
        for (let day in obj1) {
          if (day !== 'Product') {
            sampleObj[day] = parseInt(obj1[day] + obj2[day]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    finalArr.push(sampleObj);
  }
}
```

It can be n number of array and some array need to add key also if its not found with same Product (One array doesn't have 'Monday' key but in second array have 'Monday' key with same product then need to join both monday value).

[image]

```
this.url = ['assets/sample-dataset.xlsx', 'assets/sheet2.xlsx'];

this.jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true });
```

Two sheet two array data.Not able to merge these multiple array in one array. jsonData given two array with above image. Need to merge in one array [[array1],[array2]]

Comment: If you had started out with "here's what I tried" along with any debugging details this question would not have been closed so quickly and you would have had  chance of getting help. Otherwise it just looks like you are expecting Stackoverflow to be a  free code writing service

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cms0EXua

Comment: product name getting same. @RenéDatenschutz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash to create a pipeline function with `_.flow()`. The function flattens the sub-arrays to a single array, groups the items by the `Product`, and then maps the groups object back to array, and merges each group to a single object:

```js
const { flow, flatten, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, mergeWith, isNumber } = _ // replace with imports in your code

const fn = flow(
  flatten, // convert to a single array,
  pr(groupBy, 'Product'), // convert to groups by with the product as key
  pr(map, group => mergeWith({}, ...group, (a, b) => _.isNumber(a) ? _.add(a, b) : undefined)) // combine the items of each group to a single item 
)

const arr = [[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:13,Tuesday:1.29,Thursday:10,Friday:2,Saturday:2.1,Sunday:12},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:10,Tuesday:1.29,"Wednesday":2.6,Thursday:4.9,Friday:2,Saturday:20,Sunday:12}],[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:10,Tuesday:45,Wednesday:45,Thursday:23,Friday:2,Saturday:3,Sunday:2},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Thursday:34,Friday:5,Saturday:34,Sunday:34}]]

const result = fn(arr)


console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```

And a terser version using lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, flatten, groupBy, map, mergeAllWith, isNumber } = _ // replace with imports in your code

const fn = flow(
  flatten, // convert to a single array,
  groupBy('Product'), // convert to groups by with the product as key
  map(mergeAllWith((a, b) => _.isNumber(a) ? _.add(a, b) : undefined)) // combine the items of each group to a single item 
)

const arr = [[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:13,Tuesday:1.29,Thursday:10,Friday:2,Saturday:2.1,Sunday:12},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:10,Tuesday:1.29,"Wednesday":2.6,Thursday:4.9,Friday:2,Saturday:20,Sunday:12}],[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:10,Tuesday:45,Wednesday:45,Thursday:23,Friday:2,Saturday:3,Sunday:2},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Thursday:34,Friday:5,Saturday:34,Sunday:34}]]

const result = fn(arr)


console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `forEach`. The end goal is to create an accumulator object with all the `Product` as key and the values you need in the output array as it's value. Create a `defaultObj` with all the days of the week as keys and `0` as value. In the nested array loop, [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `Product` and the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the `days` keys as a separate object. Loop through the keys of `days` and update the respective `Product`'s values

```js
const arr = [[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:13,Tuesday:1.29,Thursday:10,Friday:2,Saturday:2.1,Sunday:12},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:10,Tuesday:1.29,"Wednesday":2.6,Thursday:4.9,Friday:2,Saturday:20,Sunday:12}],[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:10,Tuesday:45,Wednesday:45,Thursday:23,Friday:2,Saturday:3,Sunday:2},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Thursday:34,Friday:5,Saturday:34,Sunday:34}]],
    defaultObj = { Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Saturday: 0, Sunday: 0 },
    group = { };

arr.forEach(inner => {
  inner.forEach(({ Product, ...days }) => {
    group[Product] = group[Product] || { Product, ...defaultObj };
    for (const key in days)
      group[Product][key] += days[key];
  })
})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```

This is what the `group` object will look like

```
{
  "Men's Cut and Sewn": {
    "Product": "Men's Cut and Sewn",
    "Monday": 23,
    "Tuesday": 46.29,
    "Wednesday": 45,
    "Thursday": 33,
    "Friday": 4,
    "Saturday": 5.1,
    "Sunday": 14
  },
  "Men's Inner": {
    "Product": "Men's Inner",
    "Monday": 11,
    "Tuesday": 2.29,
    "Wednesday": 2.6,
    "Thursday": 38.9,
    "Friday": 7,
    "Saturday": 54,
    "Sunday": 46
  }
}
```

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of this object as an array

---

The above code will add a value for all the days of the week. Let's say `Men's Cut and Sewn` product doesn't have a value for `Monday` in either of the arrays and you don't want a `Monday` key with 0 as value in the output. Instead of using a `defaultObj`, you can add an additional `if-else` to to check if the day has been already added.

```js
const arr = [[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:13,Tuesday:1.29,Thursday:10,Friday:2,Saturday:2.1,Sunday:12},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:10,Tuesday:1.29,"Wednesday":2.6,Thursday:4.9,Friday:2,Saturday:20,Sunday:12}],[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:10,Tuesday:45,Wednesday:45,Thursday:23,Friday:2,Saturday:3,Sunday:2},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Thursday:34,Friday:5,Saturday:34,Sunday:34}]],
    group = { };

arr.forEach(inner => {
  inner.forEach(({ Product, ...days }) => {
    group[Product] = group[Product] || { Product };
    for (const key in days) {
      if(group[Product][key])
        group[Product][key] += days[key];
      else 
        group[Product][key] = days[key];
    }
  })
})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:13,Tuesday:1.29,Thursday:10,Friday:2,Saturday:2.1,Sunday:12},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:10,Tuesday:1.29,"Wednesday":2.6,Thursday:4.9,Friday:2,Saturday:20,Sunday:12}],[{Product:"Men's Cut and Sewn",Monday:10,Tuesday:45,Wednesday:45,Thursday:23,Friday:2,Saturday:3,Sunday:2},{Product:"Men's Inner",Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Thursday:34,Friday:5,Saturday:34,Sunday:34}]],
    group = { };

arr.forEach(inner => {
  inner.forEach(({ Product, ...days }) => {
    group[Product] = group[Product] || { Product };
    for (const key in days) {
      if(group[Product][key])
        group[Product][key] += days[key];
      else 
        group[Product][key] = days[key];
    }
  })
})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```